Mystery episode or movie about a man investigates time travel related cases
I'm looking for a TV-show from the 90s that I remember two episodes or two situations from the same movie:
First one in which a scientist does experiments on mice and suddenly he makes the mouse disappear, then he notices its food getting less. The mouse appeared again after a while and he relizes that it didn't disappear, it just got very fast that he couldn't see it. Eventually the mouse dies because the time frequency issue. 
So he took the same formula and becomes very fast and spend the short time struggling to go back to his normal status. He had to take a sort of device from a lab while his colleague is demonstrating to his students and they thought it is a bomb! Because he was very fast, eventually the scientist dies. 
The second one: about a man got an electrical shock inside a tunnel or mine which sends him back one week in time, and he got stuck on that week loop (the week repeats itself). He seeks the series starring (a man like a detective) for help. 

Can you tell us when about you think you watched it? Was it a newer show (past 20 years) or something older? In English, Color, Etc? Was the show serialized at all or was each episode completely separate (anthology)?

Duplicate of Identify this British miniseries about a scientist since you're looking for The Infinite Worlds of H.G. Wells. Those two stories were feautured on it. The Q's don't bear much resemblance but frankly this has come up so many times here in ID. If this is wrong, please let me know.

Walt, you are amazing. This is it, thank you very much.

Possibly Quantum Leap. Had a sidekick who would jump him from time to time. 
Former scientist Sam Beckett finds himself trapped in time due to an experiment gone awry, leaping into the body of a different person each week. Al Calavicci, at first known only as The Observer, is Sam's holographic adviser -- he provides Sam with some details about his new identity and gives him guidance on how to help the people affected by his presence. But with little memory to help guide him, our hero is forced to bluff his way through many a wacky situation.
